# Banner is showing up in English on non-English sites

Tags: feature-request, bug, localization, notification-bar

While looking at Rus.SO or Es.SO or any other non-English site, the Notification banner shows in English:

[image: Rus.SO]

[image: Es.SO]

So should this be translated into the local language (eg Russian on Rus.SO) or just left out, since it leads to pages only in English anyway?

Comment: Good question, guess it should be the same as the "site is in read only mode" banner. As can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A56z4.png), the message is in English. So, nothing should be done.